# Docking a form to another form panel

Tags: c#, forms, docking

Is it possible to dock a form1 to a panel contained in another form2?
I'm launching form1 with ShowDialog from a form2 event.

Comment: Please check this: Parent a Form to a Panel(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485149/parent-a-form-to-a-
answer by @hanspassant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with `ShowDialog` (or even `Show`), no. A form that has already been displayed as a top-level form cannot later be added as a subcontrol of any other control. You can try to keep the form within a particular set of screen bounds by monitoring the `LocationChanged` event, but that will appear jerky on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Consider extracting the controls out of `form1` into a UserControl. Use that UserControl on `form1` (assuming you need it as a form as well as the docked control), then dock the UserControl on `form2` to implement the desired functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the COMPLETELY FREE docking library to develop Visual Studio .Net style applications provided by [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/) link. Believe me, it's a commercial quality and bug-free code!