# Parent a form to a panel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a form with a treeview on one side.  Depending on what node is selected, I want to display different content on the right.  To keep code and controls manageable, my plan was to isolate content into seperate forms, and display the form inside a panel.

In my TreeView AfterSelect event, I tried instantiating the form, and setting it's Parent to a panel but I get an exception "Top-level control cannot be added to a control.":

```
Form frmShow = new MyForm();
frmShow.Parent = this.pnlHost;
```

This is not an MDI configuration, but I tried setting the forms MdiParent property to the parent form, and then setting the form's Parent property to the panel but I get an exception "Form that was specified to be the MdiParent for this form is not an MdiContainer. Parameter name: value":

```
Form frmShow = new MyForm();
frmShow.MdiParent = this;
frmShow.Parent = this.pnlConfigure;
```

I can't set the form as an MDI Container because it is not a top level form, it is actually a form that is docked inside a parent form (using the WeifenLuo docking library).

Is there some way to parent a form in a panel in a non MDI framework?

Comment: Changed to use UserControls instead!

Comment: OK, and did that solved the problems?

Comment: @Henk - Yes. user controls were the correct way to go,  Forms was a missguided approach, I should have seen that from teh start.

Comment: @Jeremy how did you add the dockpanel into a UserControl? I am trying that and when i add the forms to the dockpanel i get this error : "Invalid parent form. When using DockingMdi or SystemMdi document style, the DockPanel control must be the child control of the main MDI container form.". And it seems correct because we cannot set a UserControl as an MdiContainer. Can you give me a hint on this please?

Comment: @OlaruMircea I've got the same exception and got rid of it setting the DockPanel's property "DocumentStyle" to "DockingWindow".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would be better off creating every panel as a `UserControl`.  These are just like forms, but without the window elements.

Answer (score 22):

Just for the record, this is possible.  You can turn a Form into a child control by setting its TopLevel property to false.  Like this:

```
    private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e) {
        switch (e.Node.Name) {
            case "Node0": embedForm(new Form2()); break;
            // etc..
        }
    }
    private void embedForm(Form frm) {
        // Remove any existing form
        while (panel1.Controls.Count > 0) panel1.Controls[0].Dispose();
        // Embed new one
        frm.TopLevel = false;
        frm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        frm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        frm.Visible = true;
        panel1.Controls.Add(frm);
    }
```

A user control has less overhead.

Comment: Thanks for posting this - I agree that the op should utilize UserControls rather than Forms, but I have a completely different case where I DID need to set the parent of a Form and this little nugget is what saved the day!

Comment: I have found that using this technique means your tab order is messed up.  You tab from parent to embedded and then it never leaves.  The solution is to use a UserControl and tab order works correctly.

Answer (score 3):

> and display the form inside a panel

No, don't do that. Use UserControls instead of Forms. Creating/designing a UserControl works just like a Form and it will solve all of your problems (here).

Answer (score 1):

Set `frmShow.TopLevel = false` if you still want to use a form instead of a UserControl for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void toolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ucAdmin ucA = new ucAdmin(); //ucAdmin is a user control u had created.
    ucA.Visible = true;
    ucA.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

    this.pnlMain.Controls.Clear(); // pnlMain is the location u are going to display this user control.
    this.pnlMain.Controls.Add(ucA);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please provide a short description about the code above to improve the accuracy of the post :)