# Show a Winform 'Form' as if it were a usercontrol, within another form

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

#### Edit

The answer to [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485149/parent-a-form-to-a-panel), though an obvious solution, is insufficient for this case. I've bolded the reason in my original question explaining why I wanted it 'literally answered' - thanks LarsTech!

#### My Original Question:

I have a library with 100 WinForms *Form* screens in it that is **'Beyond My Control'** and there are a few I can share in my app. However, my app uses a tab control and I need the content of the forms to appear within the tabs instead of as popups.

When I try to new up one of the forms and add it to the controls collection of a tab, I get this error message:

**Top-level control cannot be added to a control.**

Anybody know how to get around this? I know there are other ways involving better architecture, but deadlines, backlogs, and rich new customers await. [sigh/]

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //panel1.Controls.Add(new Button());
  Form f = new Form();
  f.Controls.Add(new CheckBox());
  //f.ShowDialog();
  panel1.Controls.Add(f);
}
```

Comment: It would be pretty quick to convert an existing form to a User Control, and include that User Control in the original form, and then in your Tab Control as well. This would allow you to convert forms "on-the-fly" instead of having to change everything all at once.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parent a form to a panel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485149/parent-a-form-to-a-panel)

Comment: thanks for the input ... but I can't change them, don't want to dup them, and would like to share them. Good advice though as most situations this is the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try turning the TopLevel off:

```
f.TopLevel = false;
f.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
f.Visiible = true;
```

Now it is *essentially* a UserControl.  A word of caution though, since it's a form, it will show up in the `Application.OpenForms` collection, which is probably not your intention.

Comment: Good note on `Application.OpenForms`. It can be handled by adding a `f.TopLevel` check..

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the form's `TopLevel` property to `false`, like this:

```
f.TopLevel = false;
```

You may also want to set the `FormBorderStyle` property to `None`.

```
f.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
```

As mentioned in the comments above, it really would be best, when possible, to make it a `UserControl`.