# Multiple .cs file access one windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

For a better organisation of my code I want to split my win form in multiple *.cs files.

For example:

- for all the elements that I placed in tabPage1 I want to have access to them from let's say: "Tab1.cs";
- for all the elements that I placed in tabPage2 I want to have access to them from let's say: "Tab2.cs";

Also when I have multiple text boxes in these different pages and I want to generate an action, for example, "Key up" I want to have the definitions of these events in the specific .cs file (Tab1 or Tab2)

```
TabControl:
|
├── tapPage1/
│   ├── Tab1.cs
└── tapPage2/
    ├── Tab2.cs
```

It's a way to do this?

[image]

Comment: You can use [partial classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods#partial-classes)

Comment: User controls, one per tab page, is a pretty basic way to organize the code.  That can even be done [with forms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4485395/17034), if you already have them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep a lot of code away from the form by:

- using data binding
- injecting services
- using the MVC pattern

**Data Binding**

If you do not use data binding, you need a lot of code to fill the text boxes, combo boxes and all the other boxes with data. You also must convert numbers to string.

After having entered the data, the content of these boxes must be converted to data again. Converting back the strings to numbers is tedious an error prone.

When using [Windows Forms Data Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/windows-forms-data-binding?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8), you put your data into a class into properties. Then you assign this data object (or view model) to a binding source and the conversion between boxes and the object is done  automatically in both ways.

**Services**

The form should contain only logic closely related to how things are displayed. I.e., adding and configuring controls (usually done in the *.Designer.cs file), changing colors or enabling or disabling controls.

Business logic, e.g. calculating prices, should be extracted to service classes. You can add flexibility and testability by injecting these services into the form constructor. This is best done through interfaces.

```cs
public partial class PriceCalculationForm : Form
    private readonly IPriceCalculator _priceCalculator;

    public PriceCalculationForm(IPriceCalculator priceCalculator)
    {
        _priceCalculator = priceCalculator;
    }
}
```

This allows you to inject different versions of the calculator and you can test the service in a unit test without involving the UI.

**MVC pattern**

You can even go a step further and remove more logic from the form, by not binding to a pure data class, but to a view model class. Such a class typically implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. With this mechanism the form automatically updates when properties in the view model are modified.

You can bind to any property of a control. Typically, you would bind a property to the `Text` property of a text box, but you can additionally bind to the `Visible` or `Enabled` or the `BackColor` properties, for instance. This allows you to control the visual aspects of your form through binding.

This again allows you to remove even more code from your form, by introducing a controller (see [Model–view–controller)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

The controller is used as orchestrator between the data classes, view model classes (if you differentiate between the two), the services and the form. The services would then be injected into the controller instead of the form.  If this pattern is applied consequently, the form only contains the designer generated code.

Answer (score 0):

you can also create UserControls
each user control has its own file
you then add the user controls in the tabs

like the previous post say, try to extract as soon as possible the job done by the event handlers to an external class (which will ideally located in a dedicated csproj .... which will have its own unitTest csproj )