# How to add a MDI Child from another MDI Child using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, mdi, mdichild, mdiparent

I need Some help in this case.
I have 3 Form (Main Form , Form1 , Form 2)
Main Form That is The Parent Form (ISCONTAINER = true)
Form 1 Is child for Main Form And In the same time Parent for Form2
Form 2 Is child for Form 1.

This pic that I need to be

[image: 1]

Please I need code in vb.net

In MainForm I Write this code:

> Me.IsMdiContainer = True
> With Form1
> .MdiParent = Me
> .Show()
> End With

In Form 2 I write this code:

> With Form2
> .MdiParent = CType(Me.Parent.Parent, MainForm)
> .Show()
> End With

The Form 1 opened as child for MainForm but Form2 doesn't

Comment: It CANNOT work that way. You can only have one MdiParent container. A form that is an MdiChild cannot also be an MdiParent at the same time.  It is possible to do this WITHOUT using the MDI model, though. You can set `.TopLevel` for the "child forms" to False, then simply add them to any valid container via CODE like any other control.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4485395/17034